# session_unset and onclick

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm trying to clear a form that has been populated using PHP sessions.

```
   Your name: <input type="text" name="name" 
       value="<?php echo($_SESSION['username'])?>" >
   Your email address: <input type="text" name="email" 
       value="<?php echo($_SESSION['email'])?>">
   <br>
       <textarea name="story" cols="60" rows="10">
   <?php echo($_SESSION['story']); ?>
       </textarea> 
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

The problem is that when I hit the reset button, the form does not clear.

I think I need to use the session_unset command but no matter where I put it, the form is cleared before the reset button is pushed.

How can I combine session_unset and a reset button?

Comment: this could be done through javascript. Would you mind to post your whole `<form>` not only the contents of the `<form>`

Comment: You need to use AJAX to run a server script when the reset button is pressed.

Comment: I would rather not learn AJAX since I only have 2 hours to complete this.  IDK why you want my form tags so bad, they're useless in respect to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this is two ways. You can start giving the two submit buttons a NAME, and then make a PHP script, which unset the defined Sessions by

`<?php
if(isset($_POST['reset']){unset($_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['email']);}
?>`

And then of course change the Value to `<?=$_SESSION['username'];?>` and `<?=$_SESSION['email'];?>` - Because then it'll only show value if the two sessions contains any.

Otherwise you can do it with JQuery.

**EDIT:**

^ You should ofcourse also unset the `$_SESSION['story']` (Didn't see it at first)

**EDIT2:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("form input[type=reset]").click(function(e) {
        $("form input[name=name]").attr("value","");
        $("form input[name=email]").attr("value","");
        $("form textarea[name=story]").attr("value","");
        return false;
    });
});
```

or if you want it to reset 'anything' which is text-based:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("form input[type=reset]").click(function(e) {
        $("form input[type=text], form input[type=email], form input[type=password], form textarea").attr("value","");
        return false;
    });
});
```

^ Add more options if you like to :)

Comment: I like the if statement, the only problem is that $_POST needs the form to be submitted first, so it doesn't work.   How would you go about doing this in jQuery?

Comment: if you know how to write a quick jquery function to clear the form you could win this question

Answer (score 0):

I think the Reset button resets the form into the way it was received from the server. So that could be why it is not working. It was received with data, thus the button takes back to it's original state. I could be wrong though, haven't tried that before.

And by the way, to unset a $_SESSION, you could do this

```
unset($_SESSION['specific']);
```

or you could destroy the whole thing.

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: The reset button works before the data is stored in the session, or before the form is submitted

Comment: From what I have done, it works before you submit it. Usually it clears the whole form. It never submits from my knowledge. Try deleting something from one of inputs so that it is empty, then click Reset and see what happens.

Comment: using "unset" is not a problem.  The problem is that it unsets the value before the "reset" button is pushed

Comment: When the html is loaded in the browser is the data not there?

Comment: And why is your textarea and input tags not in a form tag? Does it submit the content to the server? It looks incomplete to me. (0.0)

Comment: They are in a form tag, I just didn't include it in my preview.   When the page is loaded, all the session data is there.

Comment: Wow. I'm clueless then. Perhaps someone who's experienced this will help you in a while. Never had such a bug in my code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm probably just going to use jQuery to clear the field.